# How can I download a file which has a name of the previous day

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to download a file which has the previous day as its name.
Example today's date: 20131021

File name: 
`20131020-blah.gz`

so far I have come up with this.. but it does not work:

```
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/'$(date +%Y%m%d -d)-blah.gz' /myFolder/Documents/
```

Answer (score 6):

```
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/"$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz" /myFolder/Documents/
```

The key part is:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday
20131020
```

Also note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: So if I enter this command tomorrow, it will be today's date right?

Comment: @user2883071 Sure, you see I didn't hardcode the date in there, but specified `yesterday`, which will be calculated relative to the current system date.

Comment: @user2883071, you *may* need to consider your time zone versus the time zone of ftp.haha.com, depending on what time of day you run the command.